# Software for rendering playlist-like audio "compositions"?

Tags: audio

I am looking for a software that takes a list of files and their associated volumes and playtimes and renders a result. It could take as input something like XSPF, but XSPF works just sequentially, e.g.:

1. A.mp3
2. B.mp3
3. C.mp3

whereas I'm looking for something that can read and render multiple audio files, starting from various points, with various volume envelopes... Basically the basic DAW-like operations:

- A.wav (start at 0:05, ramp up volume to -4dB over 10s)
- B.wav (start at 0:00, at full volume)
- C.wav (start at 0:30, from 0:10, end after 5s)

I am imagining it would take an XML or otherwise machine-readable description, load these audio files and render them into a single resulting audiofile. Basically a very stripped down DAW that one can operate from CLI.

I know about https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/ which is fairly close, but I would prefer not having to write any Python code myself, just present it with a list of operations.

Answer (score 1):

The Wolfram Language provides built-in support for both programmatic and interactive audio processing, fully integrated with the Wolfram Language's powerful mathematical and algorithmic capabilities. You can create and import sound files, manipulate them with built-in functions, apply linear and nonlinear filters, and visualize them in any number of ways. See [Wolfram Language Audio Basics Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AudioBasics.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can, potentially do this all from the command line with FFMPEG - however the command line tends to be long and convoluted the Audio page gives some [examples](https://trac.ffmpdireg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation).

You could take a look at using the Audio part of [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy) which is a pythonic wrapper for FFMPEG operations.